# CI & Docker-in-a-Docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to integrate docker into my CI platform. After getting this working properly with a `Docker-in-a-docker` solution, I came across a blog post by one of the `Docker` maintainers, where he says that instead of using a `Docker-in-a-docker` solution for my CI, I should instead simply mount the `/var/run/docker.sock` to my CI container.

> https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/
>
> Simply put, when you start your CI container (Jenkins or other), instead of hacking something together with Docker-in-Docker, start it with:
>
> `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...`

So I tried this. I ran the following command:

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkins`

Using jenkins as my CI container.

When running the above command, jenkins starts up properly, and I can jump into the container to see that the `docker.sock` file is located in the `/var/run/` path.

However, when I run the command: `docker`, the machine returns with the following message:

`bash: docker: command not found`

Does anyone know what I am missing in order to make this work per the author's instructions?

I am using Docker `v. 1.11.1`, on a fresh CentOS 7 box.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out today. The above command will work so long as the `docker` daemon + dependencies are added to the container. In my case, I ended up writing a simple `Dockerfile`, which also included the line:

`RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

This installed Docker on the container, and when I ran `docker images` from within the container, I could see all of the images from my host machine. I am now able to use all of the `docker` commands from within the container.